# Why does Sqoop ignore column names when importing data from SQL Database

Tags: azure, sqoop

I have following command for transferring data from my SQL database to my Azure Data Lake:

```
sqoop-import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://MYDB.database.windows.net:1433;username=MYUSERNAME@MYDB;password=MYPW;database=MYDb" --table TABLENAME --target-dir adl://TESTTT.azuredatalakestore.net/Sqoop/TABLENAME
```

The result is fine except the fact that it doesn't include column names, is there a way to include these column names?

[image]

Comment: Are you importing into a table or only in HDFS directory ? Your sqoop job is failing to import few column? please clarify ?

Comment: Into a HDFS directory. My sqoop job imports the data itself correctly, but it ignores the column names. (For example the first column should be PKey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically Sqoop import doesn't support column name while importing data into HDFS. If you want to carry the schema with the data then you might consider having Sqoop to import data into Avro file format.

Other work around is that, you can use Sqoop Hive import to import the entire table as Hive table on your Hadoop Environment.

Here is good read reference for Hive import.

1. [Sqoop Hive Import](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.3/bk_dataintegration/content/using_sqoop_to_move_data_into_hive.html)
2. [Sqoop Importing data into Hive.](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive)

Comment: Clear! Thank you for the recommondations!

Comment: is thr any way to skip headers for avro file if there is no data available for table.?